# Rails: generate URL from class name and ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I've got a situation where I will have a big array that includes references to objects like:

```
array=[['Vendor',1],['Comment',2]]
```

I'd really like to be able to create a link to the objects in this array. It seems to me that since I know the class name and the id I should be able to generate the link, but so far I haven't figured out how to do it without instantiating an object.

I know I could do:

```
array.each do |i|
  = link_to i[0].constantize.find(i[1])
end
```

... but that's tons of overhead. Any suggestions on how to build the link with just the class name as a string and an ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up just forgoing the link helpers and building this manually:

```
[nil,array[0].downcase.pluralize,array[1]].join("/")
```

Probably not the most elegant or robust solution, but it covers the cases I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inflections and dynamically compute path helper :

```
array.each do |i|
  = link_to 'show', send( "#{i[0].underscore}_path", i[1] )
end
```

But this won't work if you have nested or namespaced resources.